# Are community wiki posts no longer encouraged?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I recently asked [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831830/what-are-your-gcc-g-debug-flags) that was put on hold for being primarily opinion-based. While I do agree it does encourage a wide array of answers, where it might not be possible to vote one over another, I believe that answers could be potentially useful to both me and other Stack Overflow users in the future.

My immediate reaction was to suggest turning it into a community wiki. However, one user told me that community wikis are never actually used "to the point that I'm not even sure what it's useful for any more." I just read ["The Future of Community Wiki"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/) and still believe that my question would make for a reasonably good community wiki.

Without succumbing to [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378), I suppose my question finally boils down to two points:

1. Are community wiki posts no longer encouraged? I was thinking about rewording my question so as to create a community wiki, but if they're always discouraged then this is a dead-end approach.
2. How could I best rewrite my question so that it would be accepted on Stack Overflow? There isn't "an answer" per se to this type of question - does that really mean it has no place whatsoever on this site?

Comment: 1: nah, they're fine where warranted. 2: if the question doesn't have an answer... it's not going to fit within our Q/A format, due to not having an A.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How could I best rewrite my question so that it would be accepted on Stack Overflow?

You don't. You're fundamentally asking for opinions, not an objective question that has a verifiably correct answer. Such questions aren't appropriate here.

> here isn't "an answer" per se to this type of question - does that really mean it has no place whatsoever on this site?

There's Chat, I guess. That's about it. That wouldn't be appropriate as a proper Question on any of the main sites.

> Are community wiki posts no longer encouraged?

There are *very* few situations in which it's appropriate for a question.  So few, that only moderators are allowed to do it, because it's so often misused.

Note that Community Wiki posts aren't for posts that violate the site's rules and aren't appropriate here, as some sort of get out of jail free card. Community Wiki is a way of indicating that a post is not one person's answer, but rather a collaborative work of many people, and that one person cannot be credited (or faulted) with the result, as well as indicating that other users are welcome to edit *the content* of the post, and change the underlying meaning if they feel they can improve it, rather than limiting editing to the presentation *of the original author's ideas* (because there *is* no original author in a CW post).

This fundamental idea, of a collaborative post that's not one user's contribution, makes sense for answers (hence why any user can make their own answer CW), but doesn't really make sense for a question. What does it mean for a question to only be able to be answered by a collaborative work, and not one person's answer? It doesn't even really make sense, hence why people say it doesn't really have a point and generally shouldn't be used any more.

Comment: I suppose I was envisioning a list of answers where seeing all of them listed consecutively and annotated appropriately would be beneficial to SO users. My idea was that this is only a reasonable situation if the entire community can collaboratively improve this list -- hence why I thought a community wiki was a solution.

Comment: But your response here has confirmed what I have already recognized - that SO only wants question->answer, question->answer. +1

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll there are maybe handful of cases where enough people explicitly stepped in to maintain such wiki answer for borderline on-topic questions (I know of one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) but it is an exception and to my knowledge had enough discussions on meta to keep post around (even if that one  now clearly off-topic). It is quite unlikely to gain enough support now for new clearly off-topic question to try to get "let's keep off-topic with wiki list" treatment for it.